# bad request while using google index api in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, client, bad-request

Hello evrey one i want to make a script that update my new urls of my website by using google indexing api from **http://localhost:8000/test.html**
i add **http://localhost:8000** to Authorised JavaScript origins in the client ID
but i have error 400 :

```
Sign-in successful

cb=gapi.loaded_0:228 GET https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/indexing/v3/rest?pp=0&fields=kind%2Cname%2Cversion%2CrootUrl%2CservicePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods%2CbatchPath%2Cid&key='my api' 400
wh @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:228
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:228
xh @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:229
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:229
d @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:186
b @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:181


Error loading GAPI client for API 
{error: {…}}
error:
code: 400
message: "Request contains an invalid argument."
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

i change the browser from chrome to edge it work one time then i shutdown my pc but day after the problem apear again.
i am using the api expoler script : [link](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/reference/indexing/rest/v3/urlNotifications/publish)
i put the script and the console log as image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Sample JavaScript code for indexing.urlNotifications.publish
     * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
     * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
     */

    function authenticate() {
      return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Sign-in successful");
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Error signing in", err);
          });
    }

    function loadClient() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey("My-API");
      return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/indexing/v3/rest")
        .then(function() {
            console.log("GAPI client loaded for API");
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err);
          });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    function execute() {
      return gapi.client.indexing.urlNotifications.publish({
          "resource": {
            "url": "example",
            "type": "URL_UPDATED"
          }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error("Execute error", err);
          });
    }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "my OAuth client ID"
      });
    });
  </script>
  <button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
  <button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
</body>

</html>
```

[here the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD50t.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to god, i try loadClient then authenticate and it works

```
  like this <button onclick="loadClient().then(authenticate)">authorize and load</button>
```

then i use **chrome incognito**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Sample JavaScript code for indexing.urlNotifications.publish
     * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
     * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
     */

    function authenticate() {
      return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"})
        .then(function () { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
          function (err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
    }
    function loadClient() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey("My API");
      return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/indexing/v3/rest")
        .then(function () { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function (err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    function execute() {
      return gapi.client.indexing.urlNotifications.publish({
        "resource": {
          "url": "my web site",
          "type": "URL_UPDATED"
        }
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
          console.log("Response", response);
        },
          function (err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
    }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", function () {
      gapi.auth2.init({client_id:"My client ID"});
    });
  </script>
  <button onclick="loadClient().then(authenticate)">authorize and load</button>
  <button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
</body>

</html>
```

```
GAPI client loaded for API
Sign-in successful
Response {result: {…}, body: "{↵  "urlNotificationMetadata": {↵    "url": "https…e": "2020-09-15T20:34:07.091671446Z"↵    }↵  }↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for indexing.urlNotifications.publish
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/indexing/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.indexing.urlNotifications.publish({
      "resource": {}
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "samplexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

not working and

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      /**
       * Sample JavaScript code for indexing.urlNotifications.publish
       * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
       * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
       */
    
      function authenticate() {
        return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"})
            .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                  function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
      }
      function loadClient() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/indexing/v3/rest")
            .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
                  function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
      }
      // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
      function execute() {
        return gapi.client.indexing.urlNotifications.publish({
          "resource": {}
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                    console.log("Response", response);
                  },
                  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
      }
      gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "samplexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"});
      });
    </script>
    <button onclick="loadClient().then(authenticate)">authorize and load</button>
    <button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

not working all error;
code code: 400
message: "Request contains an invalid argument."
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).